# Handling observable errors inside a component when subscription / observable is defined external to component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have written an example below similar to my scenario (simplified).

Currently, I have a generic form component the emits a submit event. When this is handled outside of the component we subscribe to a request (defined outside of form).

However, I would like the form to know if there was an error with the request so it can reset. I want to avoid handling the error outside of the component (as someone may not handle it).

I was wondering how I could provide the subscription to the component or alternatively how the form can know if there was an error in an external request.

Can an `Output` receive a subscription / observable as well as `emit`? Or is there a way of providing an observable via `Input` (would need to be callable as it is created with external / dynamic data).

Event:

```
interface SubmitEvent {
   id: string;
   data: any;
}
```

Component A: A general form with submission. Not aware of specific contexts/ subscriptions.

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'my-form'
   template: `<button (click)="doSubmit()">Submit</button>`
})
export class MyForm {
   @Input() id: string;
   @Output() formSubmitted = new EventEmitter<SubmitEvent>();
   
   formValues: any;


   doSubmit(){
      this.formSubmitted.emit({ id: this.id, data: this.formValues });
      /*
      after this emit I would like to know if there was an error with the external request.
      */
 
   }
}
```

Component B: One instance of many forms. Defines the observable / request that happens on submit.

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'form-b'
   template: `<my-form [id]="'my-id'" (formSubmitted)="handleSubmit($event)"></my-form>`
})
export class FormB {

   @Input() somethingElse: string;

   constructor( private readonly httpService: HttpService ){}

   handleSubmit( event: SubmitEvent ){
      httpService.customPost( event.id, event.data, this.somethingElse ).subscribe();
      /*
      This request could be any observable. It may or may not use arguments from the event.
      */
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, I would approach it using a service.

More specifically:

1. First you create a service with a public method `submitForm(params)` which performs the submit logic, a private `Subject` that emits when the submit logic completes, and a public `Observable` that exposes the `Subject` as an `Observable`, i.e. something like this

public class MyService {
private _submitFormSubject = new Subject()
public submitForm$ = _submitFormSubject.asObservable()

public performSubmitForm() {
httpService.customPost( event.id, event.data, this.somethingElse )
.subscribe(this._submitFormSubject);
}
}

2. Then you inject `MyService` into the components `MyForm` and `FormB`
3. In the `ngOnInit` method of `MyForm` you subscribe to `submitForm$` and in the subscription logic you define whatever logic you need, e.g. you deal with the errors that may be emitted
4. In `FormB` you react to the event fired by `MyForm` in the method `handleSubmit` by calling the method `performSubmitForm` of `MyService`
5. The service method `performSubmitForm` does the submit and, via the private `Subject` `_submitFormSubject` you notify either the response (in case of success of the submission) or an error (in case the submit operation fails)
6. Since `MyForm` has subscribe to the `Observable` `submitForm$` it will be able to react to either the success of the failure of the submit operation